# jQuery request loop with sleep/timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout, settimeout

I've been trying to create a jQuery request loop, that reloads content every X seconds based on the result.

I have this JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    function init(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'screen.php',
            data: {
                'screen' : <?php echo $screen_id; ?>
            },
            async: true,
            success: function(r){
                JSON.parse(r, function(k, v){
                    if(k == 'screen_content'){
                        var content = v;/* $('.content').html(v); */
                    }

                    if(k == 'visible_seconds'){
                        setTimeout($('.content').html(content),v);
                        /* (function(){}).delay(timer); */
                        /* $().delay(function(msg) { console.log(msg); }, v, 'Hello'); */
                    }
                });

                /* init(); */
            }
        });
    }

    init();
});
```

The result is a JSON string with X number of "screen_content" and "visible_seconds" paired. I need to show the "screen_content" in "visible_seconds" seconds, then change the content with the next in the JSON - and when all have been shown, it all starts over (so we can get new content in)

It's seems simple in my head, but I can't create the jQuery for it :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function getContent(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'screen.php',
            data: {
                'screen' : <?php echo $screen_id; ?>
            },
            async: true,
            success: function(contentArray){
                return showAllContent(contentArray);
            }
        });
    }

    var i = 0;
    function showContent(contentArray, count){
        var currContentData = contentArray[count];
        $('.content').html(currContentData.content);
        setTimeout(function() {
            return showAllContent(contentArray);
        }, currContentData.duration);
    }

    function showAllContent(contentArray){
        if(i === contentArray.length){
            i = 0;
            return getContent(showAllContent);
        }
        return showContent(contentArray, i++);
    }

    getContent();
});
```

I have assumed that your ajax call returns data in the following structure:

```
[{
    content: 'content 1', 
    duration: 1000
}, {
    content: 'content 2',
    duration: 2000
}]
```

Fiddle with dummy function instead of ajax call [here](http://jsfiddle.net/aazhwf0s/).